# Optimize the if else condition in the code

Tags: java

Below is my code.

```
String perfIdValtxt = "";
        try {
            while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next()) {
                String perfIdVal = resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1);
                if (perfIdVal == null) {
                    perfIdValtxt = "";
                } else {
                    perfIdValtxt = perfIdVal;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I wanted to use one condition here i.e.like

```
if(perfIdVal != null){
//code
}
```

perfIdValtxt is already set up before if-else hence I wanted to optimize. Any workaround on this?

Comment: Why are you iterating results from a db query? I'd guess the optimization of the db query would be something more worthwhile pursuing than "optimizing" the if.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing exactly what you have written? Replace `if (perfIdVal == null) { perfIdValtxt = ""; } else { perfIdValtxt = perfIdVal; }` with `if(perfIdVal != null) perfIdValtxt = perfIdVal;` and you’ve successfully optimized the part with the least impact on the performance. But what is your question, actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handy way

```java
String perfIdValtxt = "";
try {
    while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next()) {
        perfIdValtxt = Optional.ofNullable(resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1)).orElse("");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String perfIdValtxt = "";
    try {
        while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next())
            if (resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1) != null)
                perfIdValtxt = resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as in the original question?

Comment: if there is at least one record that is not `null`, but the last record is returning a `null`, original code would result in `perfIdValtxt = ""` , this code would result in `perfIdValtxt` being the value of the last non-null returning record (again, I am  assuming a bunch about code posted in question)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the else clause if you assign directly the variable perfIdValtxt

```
String perfIdValtxt = "";
try {
    while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next()) {
        perfIdValtxt = resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1);
        if (perfIdValtxt == null) {
            perfIdValtxt = "";
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check if it's null set empty string otherwise set resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1) into perfIdValtxt

```
        String perfIdValtxt;
        try {
            while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next()) {
                perfIdValtxt = resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1) != null ? resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1): "";
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want perfIdValtxt to be assigned to "" if condition didn't satisfy:

```
    try {
        while (resultsOfSecurityDetails.next())
                perfIdValtxt=(resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1) != null)?resultsOfSecurityDetails.getString(1):"";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```